# Laravel Nova - Display text area content without option show content

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6, laravel-nova

I would like to display text area resource field content always without showing option "Show Content" or display it by default.

[image]

Is it possible?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### As of v1.1.4

There is now an option to always show.

```php
Textarea::make('Title')->alwaysShow()
```

### As of v1.0.19

You cannot. If you take a look at the `TextareaField.vue` (**nova/resources/js/components/Detail/TextareaField.vue**):

```
<template>
    <panel-item :field="field">
        <template slot="value">
            <excerpt :content="field.value" />
        </template>
    </panel-item>
</template>
```

Then if you take a look at `Excerpt.vue` (**nova/resources/js/components/Excerpt.vue**):

```
<div v-if="hasContent">
    <div v-if="expanded" class="markdown leading-normal" v-html="content" />

    <a
        @click="toggle"
        class="cursor-pointer dim inline-block text-primary font-bold"
        :class="{ 'mt-6': expanded }"
        aria-role="button"
    >
        {{ showHideLabel }}
    </a>
</div>
```

And the props of the vue:

```
props: {
    content: {
        type: String,
    },
},

data: () => ({ expanded: false }),
```

There's no option to pass the expanded attribute.

Comment: I have updated your answer, since new release there is an option to do it